# How to save data from BLE heart sensor to file using node.js

Tags: node.js, file, raspberry-pi, save, bluetooth-lowenergy

I will try my best to explain my problem. So I have heart rate sensor which is sending me a data via BLE connection. I checked it and it is working very well but I want it to save on raspberry pi to some kind of file. However, saving all data to file will destroy my poor raspberry so I want to only save last three logs (or even one doesnt matter) because in the next step I will be sending them to my server.

TL;DR

-Save data from BLE to a file on Raspberry Pi Zero using node.js

-Only three last logs

-Sending and saving data have to be endless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which only saves the last log (you mentioned it doesnt matter) in a file. im assuming you want to save the data in a .txt file. If this isnt the case, just switch the file extension.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = 'YOUR DATASTRING HERE';

let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt', {flags: 'w'});
writeStream.write(data);
```

The option `{flags: 'w'}` is set by default and is just doing the following:

- Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists) (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags)

So every time you execute this script, the file will be replaced.

In case you want to store your data in a .json file, you need to change the code a little bit, because `.write` only accepts strings or buffer-objects.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = {test: 'ThisIsATest'};

let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.json', {flags: 'w'});
writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are life saver

Comment: No problem, but it would be great if you mark the question as answered so that other people can see that directly ;)